# Bracket Highlighting in Textmate (javascript)

Tags: javascript, textmate

I have some gnarly functions in javascript that I am using Textmate to edit. I see an extremely short flash of the matching bracket, but it is almost imperceptible if you don't arrow over the bracket repeatedly. Is there a way to make the bracket highlight persistent?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I don't know of a way to make it persistent, but inside the brackets you can hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or go to **Edit > Select > Enclosing Brackets** to highlight (via selection) everything within the brackets.

Comment: that is very helpful, cheers. I'll probably accept it as the answer if TM simply doesn't highlight brackets. Seems like a bug to me, since it DOES flash.